# Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<number>'

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to learn d3.js from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMYkVLWc3y0&index=5&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p) I draw figures using d3.js in angular but I am getting stuck here. can anyone please tell me how can I solve this error.
I am having only one method `drawSvg()` and I am getting an error which is  `Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<number>'`

How can I fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the type of range when you call `d3.scaleLinear<TRange, TOutput>()`. Since you are using strings, you can specify the type of your range as `string`:

```
let color = d3.scaleLinear<string, number>()
            .domain([0, 60])
            .range(["red", "blue"]);
```